# How does zend framework paginator work ?

Tags: php, zend-framework, object, toarray

I`m using zend framework and its paginator to get an array in to pages. every thing work well but I have a question about the way paginator works.
First this is my code sample :

```
  $arr=array(
            'parviz','neda','yazdgerd','hooshang'
            );
    $paginator =new  Zend_Paginator(new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Array($arr));
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(5);
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber(1);
    var_dump($paginator);

    foreach ($paginator as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $key .'='.$value;
    }
```

when I use var_dump function it show sth like this :

```
object(Zend_Paginator)[43]


protected '_cacheEnabled' => boolean true
  protected '_adapter' => 
    object(Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Array)[44]
      protected '_array' => 
        array
          0 => string 'parviz' (length=5)
          1 => string 'neda' (length=3)
          2 => string 'yazdgerd' (length=5)
          3 => string 'hooshang' (length=6)
      protected '_count' => int 6
  protected '_currentItemCount' => null
  protected '_currentItems' => null
  protected '_currentPageNumber' => int 1
  protected '_filter' => null
  protected '_itemCountPerPage' => int 5
  protected '_pageCount' => int 2
  protected '_pageRange' => null
  protected '_pages' => null
  protected '_view' => null
```

and when I use `Foreach` I get my array!
How does it work? Is there any function like `__tostring()` in PHP which does these conversions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Zend_Paginator` implements the [IteratorAggregate](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/interfaceIteratorAggregate.html) interface, which allows observed `foreach` behavior.

Source: [Zend_Paginator – Usage – Rendering pages with view scripts](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.paginator.usage.html#zend.paginator.rendering)